# Detect execution in Amazon cloud from a Python script using boto3

Tags: python, aws-sdk, boto3, botocore

How can I find that my python script is being executed in AWS (EC2 instance, ECS container or Lambda) and not for example from my own workstation, within the script using ideally `boto3`.

I would expect that `boto3` has some way to say: "`True` - yep, you're in AWS" or "`False` - nope, you're not". However I could not find anything like this.

Something relatively close seems to be `boto.utils.get_instance_metadata` - this would I guess at least fail when executed on my workstation, but apparently such functionality does not even exist in `boto3`:
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/313

Comment: The wording of this question is not very clear, do you want to know IF your script executed? Did you try CloudTrail?

Comment: @EytanAvisror thanks for -1 AND providing a comment. I updated the question with more details. Let me know if it's enough.

Comment: Not that it matters, but I'm only responsible for the comment.
Regarding your Q - So you mean, you want to know if a script that ran (for example the script created an instance), was executed from a workstation, or from an EC2 instance / other AWS object?

Comment: @EytanAvisror I see. Yes, during a script execution.

Comment: Check out `Source IP address` inside CloudTrail events.

Comment: @EytanAvisror I'd make that a bit more verbose and link to some docs, and post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `requests` module to connect to the metadata server and determine if it is running in `AWS` or not.

```
import requests

try:
  resp = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254', timeout=0.001)
  print 'In AWS'
except:
  print 'Not in AWS'
```